# How to Edit the Styles For an Installed WordPress Slider Plugin With CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, slider

I installed a free responsive image slider plugin, Slider by WD, for my WordPress theme, and I need to edit the styles. Specifically, I can see that I need to edit the class `.wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0`:

[image]

You can see that I need the width of this div to span 100% of the width of its parent container `wds_container2_0`:

[image]

I need for the `max-width: 800px;` style that's applied to `.wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0` to go away, so I tried to copy and paste the styles for this class into my stylesheet, and commented out `max-width: 800px;`. But as you can see this is having no effect.

When scrolling up, in the Styles tab of the inspector, I notice that the source file / line for these styles is at (index):101

[image]

Since I can't edit the styles when doing this in my stylesheet:

```
#wds_container1_0 
#wds_container2_0 
.wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0 {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);
border-width: 0px;
border-style: none;
border-color: #000000;
border-radius: ;
border-collapse: collapse;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
width: 100% !important;
/* max-width: 800px; */
box-shadow: ;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 0;
}
```

how can I access this index file to change the width of this div to match the width of its parent container? Thanks!

**EDIT**: In WordPress, the `index.php` file that you see in the browser  is the combination of other the files - `header.php`, `footer.php`, `front-page.php` (or `page.php` depending on your setup), and maybe `sidebar.php`. So you can't search for elements in `index.php` - that file is not the same as what's getting rendered in the browser.

Instead, SSH into your server and do a `grep` command in the terminal to search for the element in question:

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403684/connecting-via-ssh-to-your-server

https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/ssh/searching/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overide the styles through your style sheet. By targeting a custom container in which the style is or by using !important(which is not advisable)

FOr example to target this "#wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0" ? you can use

```
body #wds_container2_0 .wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0 {
/**your code**/
max-width: 100%;
}
```

OR

```
body #wds_container2_0 div.wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0 {
/**your code**/
max-width: 100%;
}
```

copy the above code to you style sheet

Comment: Tried adding both of those - no effect. Also tried adding `!important` after `max-width: 100%;`.

Comment: Updated my code just realized the container was an id not class. and dont forget to clear cache(Ctrl + F5)

Comment: So really I was just missing `body` before targeting those ID's / the class. How did you know that you needed to include `body`?

Comment: Not necessarily the body tag. You can use any container closest to the id. it could have worked with just this "#wds_container2_0 div.wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0" the compiler will choose that over this "#wds_container2_0 .wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0" and also choose the later over ".wds_slideshow_image_wrap_0". You can read on CSS hierarchy. Glad it helped